# how to connect firebase db with react-native

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I've created react-native form for user authentication. it works using AsyncStorage but it does not add any data into bd
Here what error I have when submit my form[image]

And this is my submit form I send to firebase:

```
enter code heresubmitForm = async () => {
    const reg = /^\+?3?8?(0\d{9})$/

    if(!this.state.phone.match(reg)) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Wrong phone number !')
    } else if( this.state.username.length < 1) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Username has to be not empty !')
    } else { 
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('userPhone', this.state.phone)
      User.phone = this.state.phone
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + User.phone).set({ username: this.state.username })
      this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share some more details please ?
Looks like you have not cleared the subscriptions to firebase before unmounting.

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors

1. The error is not related to firebase, but to the `async-storage` package. Please try using the latest one.
2. You have not cleared firebase subscriptions before unmounting the component.

The latest link to `async-storage` you can use https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install